# does react-native-paper support RTL?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-paper

i want to change the placeholder direction to RTL but it doesnt work at all

this is the code

```
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

<TextInput textAlign="right" placeholder="RTL Text" />
```